# Creating an application such as notepad in Windows with the same memory usage

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-interface, memory

I've been playing around with GLFW, OpenGL, SDL2 and whatnot for making GUI's and games, but no matter what I do, the actual application itself uses roughly 20mb ram with nothing in the display, just a blank program. Contrary to this, and same with `cmd`, notepad in task manager uses litterally 0.1-0.2mb ram with the actual program itself running?

Same with Cmd in a sense, it uses roughly 0.4mb. How is this even possible if the most baseline library that uses windows API to make a window uses at least 20mb? What can you do to make a program such as notepad the way it is made (ie, uses like less than 1mb ram).

It seems quite odd since it needs to load a font, then the textures of the text, that alone in a simple SDL2 program uses atleast 5mb ram for the texture of such a size of the text I have in notepad, let alone the 30mb or so ram it uses and frees for loading the font.

Am I missing some special way of making applications in windows, and linux and mac for that matter where their text editors use almost the same as notepad too.

Any response would be appreciated :)!

Comment: Games tend to do things quite differently than other desktop applications. You could browse through the Notepad++ source code to see a more application specific way of doing things. https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus

Comment: You don't need any library or framework for a basic Windows "notepad". Just create a window and add a child edit control like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-a-multiline-edit-control) for example.

Comment: If you want to write an application as svelte as Notepad, do what Notepad’s author did and write to the win32 API directly, without linking to any third party libraries.  Every library you link to carries some overhead with it, and modern libraries tend to carry much more overhead, if only because they were designed to run on modern computers where RAM is assumed to be plentiful, so they tend to use more RAM in order to get more powerful functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad's kind of heavy. I've gotten it down to about 200k.

Link against nothing but kernel32, user32, gdi32, advapi32 (if you must). Everything else can be done by hand; if you only do what you need it weighs less than loading the dlls. Implement `RawEntryPoint()` instead of `WinMain()` (don't forget to call `ExitProcess()` instead of falling off the end; user32 creates a background thread now). Turn off the security features in the project build options; they link against C functions you may not have. Implement memcpy, memmove, memset, and avoid more than 4k in a single function frame to avoid emitting calls to _chkstk (unless you know how to implement it). Implement whatever C standard library functions you call. malloc's just HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), ...). It all works.

I did all this because I wanted to not ship the C standard library (it's a pill), not because it saves that last 1mb of RAM.

With UCRT available in Windows 10, linking against the C standard library's supposed to be less of a pill, but the documentation is not up to snuff and I haven't figured out how yet. I only put an hour into trying because, well, we can't use it for six more years anyway to avoid dependency inversion.

Comment: A good reference is the venerable [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) book which talks about the absolute bare minimum you need to do in C.

Comment: @tadman: It's out of date. The lastest compiler started (as of no less recently than late 2019) to invoke memset itself.

Comment: It'll require some adaptations, but it's certainly going to illustrate how lean you can get things.

Comment: @Joshua VC has been doing that for some time. You can use `SecureZeroMemory` instead.

Comment: @dxiv: If you can convince the compiler to invoke SecureZeroMemory rather than memset I'd like to know about it. But if you don't care about making it fast, memset is trivial anyway.

Comment: @Joshua Right. What I meant is using e.g. `WNDCLASS wc; SecureZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(wc)); /* no crt */` instead of `WNDCLASS wc = { 0 }; /* memset */`.